# How do I restrict view/edit access to a custom content type node to only the user it belongs to?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

There is a content type; let's call it Contract. I have an user role; let's call it Consultant.

I added a Consultant field to the Contract content type with Entity Reference.

How can I restrict access to view/edit that specific node to only the user it belongs to?

Comment: make use of hook_node_access: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Node access user reference](https://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) module.

> Gives content access permissions to users for content that references the users with User reference or Entity reference.